# How to get the number of rows in an excel file and use it in another formula in the same sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office, excel-2016

There is a web application generating output into an excel file based on the filters users select. Therefore, the number of rows in the output file may differ. I can edit the excel template but the application code.

The excel file has two different tabs, in the second tab I need to use a VLOOKUP to retrieve some values from the first tab. After the file is generated, I use the function below to retrieve those values, it works fine:

```
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,'Budget Analysis - P1'!$B$3:$G$500,3,FALSE),"")
```

I want to add this function to the excel template, the problem is I don't know how many rows there will be, so I can't directly use something like 500. When I add the function like below in the template, it works.

```
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,'Budget Analysis - P1'!$B$3:$G$1000000,3,FALSE),"")
```

However, I am not happy of using G1000000 in the data range, looking for more professional and elegant solution. I can find the number of rows in the excel using the formula below:

```
=MIN(ROW(data))+ROWS(data)-1
```

What I need is something like that:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,'Budget Analysis - P1'!$B$3:$G${=MIN(ROW(data))+ROWS(data)-1},3,FALSE),"")
```

I couldn't find the correct syntax or logic for that. I appreciate if you may help.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP is optimised an can use full column references:

```
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,'Budget Analysis - P1'!$B:$G,3,FALSE),"")
```

But if that is not acceptable and  you want to limit it for some reason we can replace:

```
'Budget Analysis - P1'!$B$3:$G$500
```

With

```
'Budget Analysis - P1'!$B$3:INDEX('Budget Analysis - P1'!$G:$G,MIN(ROW(data))+ROWS(data)-1)
```

so:

```
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,'Budget Analysis - P1'!$B$3:INDEX('Budget Analysis - P1'!$G:$G,MIN(ROW(data))+ROWS(data)-1),3,FALSE),"")
```

As you can see that becomes very unreadable and most likely will not save any time in the calculations.